# Segfault running cmp 'A', %al‽

Tags: linux, assembly, segmentation-fault, x86-64

For my own sick pleasure, I'm writing a small program in x86_64 assembly for Linux. However, I've encountered a segfault that makes absolutely no sense to me, in an instruction comparing an immediate operand to a register. What gives?

Here's the code leading up to the crash:

```
_start:
    sub $8, %rsp
    mov %rsp, %rbx
    lea le_string(%rip), %rsi
    mov %rsi, %rdi
    add $8, %rdi
    mov $26, %cl
    mov (%rsi), %al
    cmp 'A', %al /* This line segfaults */
    /* snip code that never runs */

le_string:
.ascii "YrFgevat"
```

I'm assembling with `gcc -nostdlib`, which is calling the GNU assembler.

Dumping the registers after the crash reveals:

- `%rsi` contains the expected pointer to the string
- `%al` contains the expected first character in the string
- `%rip` points to an instruction that doesn't touch memory

Please ignore the lack of normal calling conventions—I'm not calling out to anything besides the syscall interface, and this crashes before it's even gotten that far!

Comment: Whats that about? Asking a question and immediately answering it?

Comment: I meant to ask the question, but before I got it submitted (and after crashing my browser multiple times) I found the answer. I went ahead and submitted the question and answered it in case anyone else happens to stumble across the same problem. Incidentally, Stack Overflow has a checkbox on the 'Ask Question' page that lets you submit an answer with your question.

Comment: it's a blog type of Q&A, it's perfectly allowed, reference http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question as well as http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions "Please look around to see if your question has been asked before. It’s also OK to ask and answer your own question. "

Comment: in this case I would like to ask to specify which assembler you use (nasm probably?), not all assemblers use the same $ constant convention.

Comment: Good point! It's the GNU assembler (`as`), and I've updated the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 5):

`'A'` is being interpreted as an address after all. If you want to use it as a constant, you need to write:

```
cmp $'A', %al
```